# How to adjust image brightness in Android with OpenCV?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I created an example image with brightness adjusted in Android. I used Bitmap to adjust the brightness but it takes a very long time to run. Instead, I want to set the image brightness in Android using OpenCV.

This is my example code, but it only changes the colour of the image:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.a001);
int width = bmp.getWidth();
int height = bmp.getHeight();
Mat mRgba = new Mat(width, height, CvType.CV_8UC1);
Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, mRgba);
Mat mRay = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mRay, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2RGB, 4);
Utils.matToBitmap(mRay, bmp);
mImageview_01.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

**[Update]** 
I try add code, but it error

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.a001);
int width = bmp.getWidth();
int height = bmp.getHeight();
Mat mRgba = new Mat(width, height, CvType.CV_8UC1);
Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, mRgba);
Mat mRay = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mRay, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2RGB, 4);
/*
* Use Adaptive Thresholding on the grayscaled Mats crop -> threshed Mat
* src, Mat dst, double maxValue, int adaptiveMethod, int thresholdType,
* int blockSize, double C
*/
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(threshed, threshed, 255,
            Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 15, 8);
Utils.matToBitmap(mRay, bmp);
mImageview_01.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

**[Error]**

```
CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp:796: error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function void cv::adaptiveThreshold(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, double, int, int, int, double)
```

Pls view examples of what I'm trying to do [here](http://shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/07/set-brightness-of-imageincreasedecrease.html).

Comment: Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mRay, Imgproc.CV_MEDIAN, 4); // this is most probably wrong. you're supposed to feed in Imgproc.COLOR_* values here, by pure chance Imgproc.CV_MEDIAN is 3, which gets interpreted as COLOR_BGRA2RGB. not what you wanted, right ?

Comment: Ok, this is my mistake, but this is not my problem. I want to set brightness, I don't need change colour. Pls view link example.

Comment: Use Core.convertScaleAbs, see https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#convertscaleabs

Answer (score 1):

There is many fast and easy ways to adjust a bitmap brightness, such as [ColorMatrix](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix) or [RenderScript](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute). But if you still considered to use `OpenCV` that's the way :

```
private Bitmap changeBrightness(Bitmap bmp, int value){
    Mat src = new Mat(bmap.getHeight(),bmap.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmap,src);
    src.convertTo(src,-1,1,value);
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.cols(),src.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(src,result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

check the example given at Increase/Decrease Brightness of Image

pls see this

```
    int brightness;
 SeekBar seekBarBrightness=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
 seekBarBrightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

     @Override
     public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {


     }

     @Override
     public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {


     }

     @Override
     public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {

       Bitmap newBitMap  =   doBrightness(bitMap,progress);

       imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitMap);

     }
    });




    public static Bitmap doBrightness(Bitmap src, int value)
    {
        // image size
        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();
        // create output bitmap
        Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
        // color information
        int A, R, G, B;
        int pixel;

        // scan through all pixels
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
                    {
                        // get pixel color
                        pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
                        A = Color.alpha(pixel);
                        R = Color.red(pixel);
                        G = Color.green(pixel);
                        B = Color.blue(pixel);

                        // increase/decrease each channel
                        R += value;
                        if (R > 255)
                            {
                                R = 255;
                            } else if (R < 0)
                            {
                                R = 0;
                            }

                        G += value;
                        if (G > 255)
                            {
                                G = 255;
                            } else if (G < 0)
                            {
                                G = 0;
                            }

                        B += value;
                        if (B > 255)
                            {
                                B = 255;
                            } else if (B < 0)
                            {
                                B = 0;
                            }

                        // apply new pixel color to output bitmap
                        bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
                    }
            }

        // return final image
        return bmOut;
    }
```

Comment: The question is asked to adjust image brightness in Android with OpenCV and your answer does not include OpenCV at all.