# How to send value from View object(SeekBar) to running background thread?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am developing a client-server application.
The client is android.
The server is my computer.
The server is sending array of bytes to the client, the client build images from the byte array and displays them (frame after frame) through ImageView.

I am using AsyncTask to open socket to the server and building the images. So far, everything is working fine.

Now, i want to add SeekBar in order to change the brightness of the image.

**My problem is to how to send the seekbar value to the function that build the images?**

```
public void onClickConnect(View view)
{
    // connect to the server
    new ConnectTask().execute("");
}

public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, Bitmap, TcpClient> {

    @Override
    protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message)
    {
        //we create a TCPClient object and
        mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnBitmapReceived() {
            @Override
            public void bitmapReceived(Bitmap bitmap) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                publishProgress(bitmap);
            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... bitmap) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(bitmap); 

        //iv is the ImageView object that display the images
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap[0]);
    }
}

public class TcpClient {    
    private OnBitmapReceived mBitmapListener = null;    
    public TcpClient(OnBitmapReceived listener) {
        mBitmapListener = listener;
    }   
    public void run() {     
    mRun = true;        
    //creating a socket to make the connection with the server
    .....       
    while (mRun){           
        .....   
        //build color array
        **// HERE I NEED THE VALUE FROM THE SEEK BAR**          
        for(int i=0;i<bytePerFrame;i=i+2)                   
            {
                pixel = ((frameBytes[i] << 8) & 0x0000ff00) | (frameBytes[i+1] & 0x000000ff);
                colors[pixelIndex]=pixel;
                pixelIndex++;
            }                   
        Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();  
        c.drawBitmap(colors, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height, false, paint);          
        if(mBitmap!=null && mBitmapListener != null)
            {
                    mBitmapListener.bitmapReceived(mBitmap);
            }               
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you can have a wrapper class which will hold wrap the seekbar value in and Bitmap in it. You can send it over Sockets by serializing this class.

Comment: I want to change the brightness of the image via the android, before
i put the pixel in the colors array

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958792/how-to-adjust-image-brightness-in-android-with-opencv

Comment: I know how to change the brightness, i do not know how to pass the value of the SeekBar to the function (TcpClient.run())

Comment: What i need is to send message to the AsyncTask every time the seekbar 
is change
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Check folloowing example to change brightness of image.

> Image brightness can be changed by increasing/decreasing R,G,B values together.

http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/image-processing-brightness-over-image/